# JQuery - slide up and down a specific distance

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a list which has the list items display inline-block so they are horizontal.

I am trying to use jquery to slide the elements up by 20px when they are hovered over and back down 20px when the mouse leaves.

Exactly like the product images here: http://www.google.co.uk/nexus/

slideUp and slideDown doesnt seem to allow this.  How can this be achieved?

Also, if it provides a smoother effect I would be open to using a css transition, but again, i dont know how to do this.

My markup is as following:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery.animate(): http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$("element").animate({marginTop : "-20px"}, 500);
```

Here's a fiddle of a CSS transforms approach (no javascript) using the example markup provided by samrap: http://jsfiddle.net/qAeFH/

Comment: this is good. plus i disabled javascript to see if the nexus hover works without js and it does. So if you want it to be exactly like the nexus page, this is the route to go. @MartyWallace

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery.css();

```
$('#menu').css('top', '0px');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samrap/PAF2f/)

Answer (score 1):

I think JS is overkilled for this task. You could simply use CSS. The trick is either to change the `top` or `transform: translate` properties. In the first case you probably need `position:relative`.

You can see a live demo of `transform` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nMztX/) and a demo of `top` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wzqvA/1/).

Comment: I like this answer the best, but I'd consider adding 10px padding to the hover to prevent the "jiggle" when hovering near the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick CSS example if you choose to go that route. 
http://jsfiddle.net/7hZkG/4/

```
#slide-up li{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;

    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;

    top:0px;
}

#slide-up li:hover{
    top:-10px;

    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add this effect on each list item using jQuery, you can do the following:

```
$("li").hover( function () {
  $(this).animate({marginTop: "-20px"}, 500);
},
function () {
  $(this).animate({marginTop: "0"}, 500);
}
);
```

The *500* is to control the animation speed in miliseconds.